# Variable acts differently according to position of breakpoint

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

This is a really strange issue, and I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

I have two string arrays, declared at the top of the class:

```
String[] artistsURLIndexArray;
String[] artistsOnlyArray;
```

They are both updated in a separate thread (background worker) which is run in the onCreate method. I see in debug that everything is working, and the arrays are correctly updated.

After the background thread I have the following code (still in the onCreate method):

```
String[] test;

if(artistsOnlyArray == null) // point A
{
    test = new String[] { "empty...", "asd" }; // point B
}
else
{           
    test = new String[] { "not empty!", "asd" }; // point C
}
```

Now, when I just 'run' the application (no debug), `test[0]` is "empty...". That is, the `artistsOnlyArray` is null! This should not be the case. (Btw, I'm testing the `test` array visually with a listview.)

If I go ahead and place a breakpoint at point B and I debug the application, the app stops (breaks) here. This is expected of course, seeing as it's claiming that the `artistsOnlyArray` is null.

If I place a breakpoint at point C instead, the breakpoint is not reached. Also 'ok'.

If I place a breakpoint at point A, however, everything changes. The breakpoint is reached of course, and now it has to check whether the array is null. I press F8 to resume (I'm using Eclipse), and suddenly, `test[0]` is *"not empty!"*. I can also see that the `artistsOnlyArray` is correct (not null).

**Why is the appearance (and position) of a breakpoint causing this behaviour?**

Comment: It sounds like your background thread is either running before or after the oncreate code depending on the breakpoint. Normally the new thread won't start until your thread yields. The debugger is causing your main thread to yield and therefore giving the new thread a chance to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume this is because of the "extra time" the worker thread has when you place a breakpoint at point A.

When you don't place any breakpoint, the execution of the `if` statement happens **before** any worker thread populates the array, and so it enters on the `if`.

On the other hand, when you place a breakpoint at point A, you give time for the worker thread to populate the array. So, by the time you continue the array is already populated and it enters the `else`.

Comment: Is it possible to check when the background thread is done, and then do the if-sentence (and other) afterwards?

Comment: If you're using the `Thread` class you can use `join()`. Docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29

Answer (score 0):

You answered it yourself:  "*They are both updated in a separate thread*".

The breakpoint is possibly causing a "race" condition, where the relative timing of the threads are interfered with.  Specifically, the update thread may or may not be blocked before the breakpoint occurs.